# Gluon Mobile (JavaFX): Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.38

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

I encounter errors when I try to create a native-image of Gluon Mobile based application on Linux.

I cloned the [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloGluon) sample, and I could successfully run it as a Java application without any errors by selecting `Plugins → javafx → javafx:run` from the Maven tool window in IntelliJ IDEA.

When I want to build it as a native image on Fedora Linux, everything goes wrong. It showed the following error when I selected `Plugins → client → client:build` goal from the Maven tool window to make a native-image.

```
Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.38:build (default-cli) on project hellogluon: Error, client:build failed
```

Again I trired to build the application with -X (Produce execution debug output), and I encounter with the following:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.648 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-13T11:20:34+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.38:build (default-cli) on project hellogluon: Error, client:build failed: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/home/eloy/dev/idea-IU-203.7148.57/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn" (in directory "/home/eloy/projects/gluon-samples/HelloGluon"): error=13, Permission denied -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.38:build (default-cli) on project hellogluon: Error, client:build failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error, client:build failed
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:680)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.executeCommandLine (DefaultInvoker.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute (DefaultInvoker.java:112)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/eloy/dev/idea-IU-203.7148.57/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn" (in directory "/home/eloy/projects/gluon-samples/HelloGluon"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:589)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:675)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.executeCommandLine (DefaultInvoker.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute (DefaultInvoker.java:112)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:589)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:675)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.executeCommandLine (DefaultInvoker.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute (DefaultInvoker.java:112)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The environment spec:

- Fedora 30 XFCE
- Oracle jdk-11.0.10
- Maven 3.6.3
- graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0
- Gluon Plugin 2.8.5 (IntelliJ IDEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the mentioned issues. It seems that I did not set environment variables properly and also some OS libraries were missing. Although it is possible to use IDE’s Maven window, it is better to run your maven goals via terminal. All following commands are executed within terminal.

In order to build this application as a native-image, you need Maven, Java 11+, JavaFX 15+, Gluon Mobile and GraalVM. You can use install OpenJDK or download the [OracleJDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) from Oracle. Download the latest version of [GraalVM](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases). And do not worry about JavaFX 15 and Gluon Mobile because these dependencies will be resolved by [maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

Setup environment variables by editing `.bashrc` and add the following paths (to apply changes do not forget to logout and then login, or `source .bashrc`)

```
export JAVA_HOME="/home/eloy/dev/jdk-11.0.10"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export M2_HOME="/home/eloy/dev/apache-maven-3.6.3"
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH

export GRAALVM_HOME="/home/eloy/dev/graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0.2"
```

Make sure that you have

1. `gcc` version **6** or **higher**
2. `ld` version **2.26** or **higher**

Till now you can compile your application via `mvn client:compile`, but to complete the link phase you need the following libraries and dependencies:

Configure Yum Repository: install and enable the RPMfusion repository on your Fedora

```
dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

Then install the required libs:

```
dnf install freetype-devel glib2-devel gtk3-devel libX11-devel
dnf install libXtst-devel mesa-libGL-devel pango-devel zlib-devel
dnf install alsa-lib-devel ffmpeg-devel
dnf install libstdc++-static
```

Now you can run `mvn client:link` and you will have a `.sh` file in `../HelloGluon/target/client/x86_64-linux/` directory.

**Notice**: `client:build` just combines two goals of `client:compile` and `client:link` and runs each of them automatically.

PS These steps are tested on Fedora 30, 31, and 32.