# GraalVM Library is not linking in linux mint

Tags: java, javafx, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I have built a native image application using **(GraalVM 22.1.0)** in Mac OS environment and it worked, but when trying to build the same application on linux the gluonfx:links fails, with an error of

- `undefined reference to Java_com_sun_security_auth_module_UnixSystem_getUnixInfo`
- `undefined reference to JNI_OnLoad_jaas`

I thought the problem was the libjaas.a not linking as it was not presented in the log file, so i added `<arg>-ljaas</arg>` but gave me another error which was `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljaas`

Here is the **POM** file:

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.demo4.Driver</mainClass>
                <linkerArgs>
                    <arg>-ljaas</arg>
                </linkerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.demo4/com.example.demo4.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Main Class:**

```
package com.example.demo4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("","","");
    String str = connection.toString();
    connection.close();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Label(str),500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**Error gluonfx:link**

```html
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:26 EEST 2022][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-linux-linux. This may take some time.
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:27 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:29 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:29 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'com.example.demo4.driver' (shared library)...
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:29 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:29 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [GluonFeature] enabled for config com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureImpl$IsInConfigurationAccessImpl@7cc586a8
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:30 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] GluonFeature enabled in setup com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureImpl$DuringSetupAccessImpl@65f58c6e
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (3.7s @ 0.20GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  Version info: 'GraalVM 22.1.0 Java 17 CE'
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 9.3.0)
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  Garbage collector: Serial GC
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  1 user-provided feature(s)
[Mon Sep 05 11:37:31 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   - com.gluonhq.substrate.feature.GluonFeature
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [2/7] Performing analysis...  [***********]                                                             (45.6s @ 3.08GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   13,299 (91.34%) of 14,560 classes reachable
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   25,151 (67.63%) of 37,189 fields reachable
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   70,391 (66.36%) of 106,070 methods reachable
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      663 classes,   185 fields, and 2,147 methods registered for reflection
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:17 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      114 classes,   144 fields, and   182 methods registered for JNI access
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:20 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [3/7] Building universe...                                                                               (3.2s @ 2.60GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:23 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [4/7] Parsing methods...      [**]                                                                       (3.0s @ 3.00GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:38:30 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [5/7] Inlining methods...     [****]                                                                     (6.2s @ 2.27GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [6/7] Compiling methods...    [******]                                                                  (32.8s @ 3.51GB)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] 
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]                         10.0s (9.6% of total time) in 59 GCs | Peak RSS: 5.27GB | CPU load: 6.42
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Produced artifacts:
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/graal_isolate.h (header)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/com.example.demo4.driver.h (header)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/graal_isolate_dynamic.h (header)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/com.example.demo4.driver_dynamic.h (header)
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/com.example.demo4.driver.build_artifacts.txt
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:11 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Finished generating 'com.example.demo4.driver' in 1m 43s.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:link (default-cli) @ demo4 ---
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:12 EEST 2022][INFO] Substrate is tested with the Gluon's GraalVM build which you can find at https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases.
While you can still use other GraalVM builds, there is no guarantee that these will work properly with Substrate
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:12 EEST 2022][INFO] ==================== LINK TASK ====================
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] /usr/bin/ld: /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/tmp/SVM-1662367049997/com.example.demo4.driver.o:(.data+0x6d8): undefined reference to `JNI_OnLoad_jaas'
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] /usr/bin/ld: /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/tmp/SVM-1662367049997/com.example.demo4.driver.o:(.data+0x1050): undefined reference to `Java_com_sun_security_auth_module_UnixSystem_getUnixInfo'
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Process link failed with result: 1
Check the log files under /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][INFO] Logging process [link] to file: /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/log/process-link-1662367153279.log
[Mon Sep 05 11:39:13 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Linking failed.
Check the log files under /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:49 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-05T11:39:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:link (default-cli) on project demo4: Linking failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-05T11:39:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:build (default-cli) on project demo4: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Log file**

```html
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][INFO] ==================== LINK TASK ====================
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Looking for resource: /native/linux/launcher.c
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for compile-additional-sources: gcc -c -DSUBSTRATE -I/home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/include -I/home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/include/linux -DGVM_17 -I/home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4 launcher.c
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process compile-additional-sources...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for compile-additional-sources: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for libavcodec: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs libavcodec
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for libavcodec...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lavcodec
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for libavcodec: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg libavcodec provided flags: [-lavcodec]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for libavformat: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs libavformat
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for libavformat...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lavformat
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for libavformat: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg libavformat provided flags: [-lavformat]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for libavutil: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs libavutil
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for libavutil...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lavutil
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for libavutil: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg libavutil provided flags: [-lavutil]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for alsa: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs alsa
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for alsa...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lasound
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for alsa: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg alsa provided flags: [-lasound]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] All flags: [-lgstreamer-lite, -lavcodec, -lavformat, -lavutil, -lasound]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for gl: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs gl
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for gl...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lGL
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for gl: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg gl provided flags: [-lGL]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for x11: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs x11
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for x11...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lX11
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for x11: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg x11 provided flags: [-lX11]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for gtk+-x11-3.0: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs gtk+-x11-3.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for gtk+-x11-3.0...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for gtk+-x11-3.0: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg gtk+-x11-3.0 provided flags: [-lgtk-3, -lgdk-3, -lpangocairo-1.0, -lpango-1.0, -lharfbuzz, -latk-1.0, -lcairo-gobject, -lcairo, -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0, -lgio-2.0, -lgobject-2.0, -lglib-2.0]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for freetype2: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs freetype2
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for freetype2...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lfreetype
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for freetype2: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg freetype2 provided flags: [-lfreetype]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for pangoft2: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs pangoft2
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for pangoft2...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for pangoft2: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg pangoft2 provided flags: [-lpangoft2-1.0, -lpango-1.0, -lgobject-2.0, -lglib-2.0, -lharfbuzz, -lfontconfig, -lfreetype]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for gthread-2.0: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for gthread-2.0...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for gthread-2.0: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg gthread-2.0 provided flags: [-lgthread-2.0, -pthread, -lglib-2.0]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for zlib: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs zlib
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for zlib...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lz
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for zlib: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg zlib provided flags: [-lz]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for xtst: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs xtst
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for xtst...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lXtst
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for xtst: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg xtst provided flags: [-lXtst]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for Get config for gmodule-no-export-2.0: /usr/bin/pkg-config --libs gmodule-no-export-2.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process Get config for gmodule-no-export-2.0...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] [SUB] -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for Get config for gmodule-no-export-2.0: 0
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Pkg gmodule-no-export-2.0 provided flags: [-lgmodule-2.0, -pthread, -lglib-2.0]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] All flags: [-Wl,--no-whole-archive, -lGL, -lX11, -lgtk-3, -lgdk-3, -lpangocairo-1.0, -lpango-1.0, -lharfbuzz, -latk-1.0, -lcairo-gobject, -lcairo, -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0, -lgio-2.0, -lgobject-2.0, -lglib-2.0, -lfreetype, -lpangoft2-1.0, -lpango-1.0, -lgobject-2.0, -lglib-2.0, -lharfbuzz, -lfontconfig, -lfreetype, -lgthread-2.0, -pthread, -lglib-2.0, -lstdc++, -lz, -lXtst, -lm, -lgmodule-2.0, -pthread, -lglib-2.0]
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] PB Command for link: gcc /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/demo4/launcher.o /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/tmp/SVM-1662371091887/com.example.demo4.driver.o /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libjava.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnio.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libzip.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnet.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libprefs.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libj2pkcs11.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libextnet.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libfdlibm.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libfontmanager.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libjavajpeg.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/liblcms.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt_headless.a /home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt.a -l:libjvm.a -l:liblibchelper.a -lz -ldl -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,--wrap=pow -rdynamic -lprism_es2 -lglass -lglassgtk3 -ljavafx_font -ljavafx_font_freetype -ljavafx_font_pango -ljavafx_iio -lgstreamer-lite -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lasound -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lGL -lX11 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lstdc++ -lz -lXtst -lm -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lm -ldl -o /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/demo4 -L/home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64 -L/home/yousef66/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/linux-x86_64/sdk/lib -ljaas
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Start process link...
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljaas
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][FINE] Result for link: 1
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Process link failed with result: 1
Check the log files under /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][INFO] Logging process [link] to file: /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/log/process-link-1662371194695.log
[Mon Sep 05 12:46:34 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Linking failed.
Check the log files under /home/yousef66/Desktop/demo4/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
```

Comment: Can you update your log file? It doesn't include the link command started at 10:39:55

Comment: I updated the log file

Comment: Yes, but with the _compile_ task, not the _link_ one... It is in another log file.

Comment: Yes my bad,
i added the link log file now

Comment: I had some issues with GraalVM and I could resolve it, I don't know a workable solution, but check my old answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614585/3881354

Comment: i don't think the question is related, but can you see this updated error above.

Comment: It looks like it could be related to your graal version. https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2839

Comment: Did you get the -ljaas idea from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541023/2067492

Comment: Still, incorrect log, you haven't posted the log with the link failure.

Comment: @JoséPereda i tried the updated version 22.2.0 and it did not work, and the log file you are looking for isn't it in `target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/gvm/log/client-debug0.log.1`?.

Comment: @matt Yes, Jose helped me with it and it worked on mac, but in linux mint it did not.

Comment: You can check the logs for yourself, and then post the one that contains the error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljaas`. It is recommended to use Gluon's build of GraalVM (see https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_linux).

Comment: I build it again with `<arg>-ljaas</arg>` and the link log file is now updated with that error.

Comment: Can you try using `<arg>/home/yousef66/Desktop/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libjaas.a</arg>` instead?